# Image Resolution for iOS 7 applications

Tags: ios, graphics

What pixels per inch settings do iOS 7 graphics need to be to support the high resolution display?

Answer (score 0):

The highest pixel density display for all iOS devices as of today is 326 pixels per inch.

This is the pixel density for the following devices:

- iPhone 4/4s
- iPhone 5/5C/5s
- iPod Touch 4th/5th gen
- iPad Mini 2nd gen

Note that while the non-mini iPads also have a retina display, their resolutions are exactly the same as the minis, but on a bigger screen, so the pixel density is less.  The big iPad retinas (including the iPad Airs) have a pixel density of 264 pixels per inch.